# What does Maria vomit in the movie 'The Impossible'?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, the-impossible

There is this scene in the movie 'The Impossible' when Maria (the mom, played by Naomi Watts) starts vomiting and pulls out some wiry stuff from her mouth.

What is this? Is it something from the tsunami or is it her internal tissue? (To me it looked like some internal tissue, but I was not sure or maybe I missed some conversation.)

Comment: If you're vomiting internal tissue, you're in a serious way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[According to this interview with Watts by Kevin Maher in *The Times*](https://www.thetimes.co.uk/article/naomi-watts-on-playing-a-tsunami-victim-and-diana-princess-of-wales-h2z7q3frd6b):

> In her new movie, the 44-year-old British-Australian actress Naomi
>   Watts is hit by a tsunami, bashed in the face, ripped in the chest,
>   dragged up a tree, dragged through the mud (screaming all the while)
>   and eventually dropped on to the floor of a hospital corridor, where
>   she erupts with a truly hideous vomit cocktail of oily black sludge
>   and old rope. The film is called *The Impossible* and is based on the
>   account of Maria Belton, a survivor of the Boxing Day tsunami in 2004.
>   **The vomit is the debris and organic matter that Belton swallowed
>   during her underwater ordeal** (“Actually just a piece of string and
>   blackberry jam on-set,” Watts says).

Comment: oh thank you !! The scene has been etched in my mind and is gory to even watch. good to know its just debris !!